# Compact Gimbaling propeller

Tags: propellers, propeller-pitch

does anyone know how would you create a compact gimbaling propeller, like how a rocket engine gimbals. Similar to that! Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some commercial units ([single axis](https://www.rcmodelscout.com/Electric-Motors/Micro-3D-Single-Axis-Thrust-Vectoring-Motor-Mount-Kit-Inc-2204-Brushless-Outrunner/57960) or [two axis](https://www.hobbypartz.com/02p-vectorsystem-two-2222.html)) or there are a [variety of designs you can 3D print](https://www.yeggi.com/q/thrust+vectoring/).

[image]

These designs are mainly based around a large ball joint behind the motor, but there are some designs that use [two sets of pivots like a traditional gimbal.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izXohCO6ing&ab_channel=EnergonSolutions)

If you're DIYing it, a simple way to do it is [two motors that pivot in one direction only](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?841634-X-42-Deltastorm-II-(Vectored-Thrust)), using differential thrust for the other direction.

[image]

I've also seen models where the motor mounts are attached directly to the elevons, sharing a hinge and servo.